# как добавить в чат бота второй вариант фразы?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
import vk_api, random
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


token = "свой токен"
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token) 
vk._auth_token() 
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 'айди группы') 

while True: 
    for event in longpoll.listen(): 

        
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            mess = event.obj['text'] 
            peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']
            
            if mess == "Привет": 
                vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": "Прииивееетт!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
```

Comment: Нормально опиши проблему. Почему я должен гадать, что ты хочешь получить в итоге?

Comment: Зачем вы лезете делать ботов, если не освоили `elif`

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `if mess == 'Привет':...` сделайте так:

```
if mess == 'Привет':
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        vk.method('messages.send', {'peer_id': peer_id, 'message': 'Прииивееетт!', 'random_id': random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    else:
        # Ваш второй вариант ответа
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ `КИТ KIT` конечно хороший и полностью отвечает условиям задачи, но у меня есть идея получше:

```
# Код

answers = ["Прииивееетт!", "Здарова!", "ХАЙ!"] # Варианты ответов

# Код

if mess == "Привет":
    vk.method("messages.send", { "peer_id": peer_id, "message": random.choice(answers), "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
```